# spring bean dependency injection

Tags: java

I have this class (that looks like this, pseudo-code wise):

```
   @Component
    public class classA() {
    private variable a;
    public A() {
    }
    @Autowired
    public classA(variable a) {
    this.a = a;
    }
  }
```

Basically, the variable "a" that I want to inject is a spring bean from a configuration file defined elsewhere (at run-time)

Is this the correct way to go about defining the class so that "a" gets injected from the configuration file at run-time? I was wondering how this would work if we also have a no-args constructor?

IE: If I create an instance of classA using the no-args constructor, will "a" still be properly injected?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire